# Angular ng-repeat filter to hide elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need filter for `ng-repeat`, which will hide elements.
If  `$scope.selected` will get true, i need to hide elements when `select: true` or `visible: false`

```js
$scope.selected = false;

$scope.array = [
{name: 'item1', select: true, visible: false},
{name: 'item2', select: true, visible: true},
{name: 'item3', select: false, visible: true},
{name: 'item4', select: true, visible: false},
{name: 'item5', select: false, visible: true},
]
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
 <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need use `filter`.

Live example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/vrvkfp9o/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.selected = true;
$scope.myFilter = function(item){
 return $scope.selected && (!item.visible || item.select)
}
$scope.array = [
{name: 'item1', select: true, visible: false},
{name: 'item2', select: true, visible: true},
{name: 'item3', select: false, visible: true},
{name: 'item4', select: true, visible: false},
{name: 'item5', select: false, visible: true},
]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in array|filter:myFilter">
 <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but initial $scope.selected state is - false, and then it'll get true, and this doesn't work (

Comment: You need modify function `$scope.myFilter` like this `return $scope.selected?(!item.visible || item.select):true;`. I'm **update** jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrray">
   <div ng-show="selected">
      <div ng-hide="item.visible==false && item.select==true">{{item.name}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-if:

```
<div ng-if="item.visible && selected && item.select == true">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this one:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
    <div ng-hide="selected && (!item.visible || item.select)">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```